# Extracting SIFT features of image dataset to be matched

Tags: python, dataset, feature-extraction, feature-selection, sift

I have image dataset ant want to extract its features in order to be compared with the query image to select the best features inside threshold. I'm able to extract images features and select the best ones in two corresponding images as the following code:

```
img1 = cv2.imread("path\of\training\image")
img2 = cv2.imread("path\of\query\image")

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

# find the key-points and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=100)   # or pass empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# Need to draw only good matches, so create a mask
matchesMask = [[0,0] for i in range(len(matches))]

# ratio test as per Lowe's paper
for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.8*n.distance:
        matchesMask[i]=[1,0]

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0),
               singlePointColor = (255,0,0),
               matchesMask = matchesMask,
               flags = 0)

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None,**draw_params)
plt.imshow(img3,),plt.show()
```

I want to compare the query image features with features of all images inside dataset, to select the best ones in order to recognize the specific object. How can I combine all dataset features and compare them with the query image features? can anyone please help me with thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first and naivest idea to solve your problem is: with your query image, which has some features represented by vectors, you find the nearest neighbours to those vectors in your features/vectors dataset, then the result should be the image which has most nearest features to the query features.

Basically, you have to calculate the distances between your vectors and FAISS give you some effort ways to do that.
I found this site that may help you:
https://waltyou.github.io/Faiss-In-Project-English/. The author faced the same situation as you did. And he used above way to get through it.

> "To solve this problem, you can assign multiple ids to multiple vectors of an image when building a Faiss index. In this way, after searching with multiple vectors of a picture, in the returned result, only the number of times the associated id appears can be counted, and the similarity level can be obtained."

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advices. Appreciate them.